# How to insert CSS styling for sharepoint editing mode

Tags: css, page-layout

I would like to insert a piece of CSS to a Page Layout, to let it style the page but only **when it is in the editing mode**. Is there anyway to achieve that? I know there is a Editing mode Panel, but how could I insert CSS to it?

Version = 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

    <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server">

        <!-- with the built-in control -->
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="somepath/somecss.css" runat="server" />

        <!-- classic -->
        <link href="<%$ SPUrl:~siteCollection/somepath/somecss.css %>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- inline -->
        <style>
            #sideNavBox {
                display: none;
            }

            #contentBox {
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>

    </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I didn't follow this verbatim, but I used the rationale behind this and used the snippet code generated from sharepoint. Thank you! Very helpful. A side note is that I need to wrap the <style> tags in some other tag I'm not sure of, such as  <!--MS:<style type="text/css">--> 
            #somediv {display:none;}
            <!--ME: </style>-->